# Laravel site cant be reached for this DotenvEditor

Tags: laravel-8

I am uses Dotenveditor to save the env parameters but after redirecting i faced error as

This site can’t be reachedThe connection was reset.
Try:

Checking the connection
Checking the proxy and the firewall
ERR_CONNECTION_RESET

what is mistake in my code? rest part of controller works properly.

```
if (isset($request->APP_DEBUG)) {
            $env_update = DotenvEditor::setKeys(['APP_DEBUG' => 'true']);
        } else {
            $env_update = DotenvEditor::setKeys(['APP_DEBUG' => 'false']);
        }
        if (isset($request->COOKIE_CONSENT_ENABLED)) {
            $env_update = DotenvEditor::setKeys(['COOKIE_CONSENT_ENABLED' => 'true']);
        } else {
            $env_update = DotenvEditor::setKeys(['COOKIE_CONSENT_ENABLED' => 'false']);
        }

        $env_update = DotenvEditor::setKeys([
            'APP_NAME' => preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $request->title),
            'APP_URL' => preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $request->APP_URL),
        ]);

        $env_update->save();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to update your `.env` file using `notepad++` as administrator. I Think it is much easier and user friendly. When you make the necessary changes save the file. Afterwords, I think you must reboot to the Virtual Machine (if you are using one) or restart the service in order the change takes effect to the application.

Talking about Laravel-Dotenv-Editor please try to visit [Dotenv editor](https://github.com/JackieDo/Laravel-Dotenv-Editor) in order to find more information.

Example of a `.env` file:

[image: Example of a .env file]

Comment: Hello  what changes can i do in .env?

Comment: @SeemaShelar You can for example set the parameters there. I have updated the above answer with an example.

Comment: @SeemaShelar Do you have any updates with this question? If you think the answer was useful, please mark it as accepted in order to help others too. Thank you in advance.